# Creating a test database with Prisma

Tags: unit-testing, testing, prisma, sveltekit

I'm using vitest to test my sveltekit+Prisma app with sqlite backend. For some tests, mocking Prisma is not enough and I need to populate a test database with test data.

What is the proper approach of using Prisma to create a test database? My schema specifies the data source:

```
datasource db {
  provider = "sqlite"
  url = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

Can I somehow override that with another url, and run `npx prisma db push` (or migrate) before running the test suite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have run into sane issue once, I was using nestjs and I ended up using env file for testing.
it was something like this:

```
  "test:e2e": "env-cmd -f .env.test npx prisma db push"
```

and in the schema I used it :

```
generator client {
    provider        = "prisma-client-js"
    output          = env("output")
}

datasource db {
    provider = "mysql"
    url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

the output in client to specifies where to generate the prisma client.
in the .env.test I have put the testing db URL.

Comment: Thank you, good solution! In my package.json I put the script: `"test": "env-cmd -f .env.test npx prisma db push --force-reset && vitest"`